# Why does my navbar component not work in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I am very new to Angular. In my Angular app I have a navbar folder in src/app/components/navbar and my navbar.component.ts file looks like this:

**navbar.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

**navbar.component.html**

```
<p>nav bar is working</p>
```

**index.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

but when I run localhost server it is not displaying `nav bar is working` in my index.html. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use your component in `app.component.html` page like this -

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

Not in `index.html` because this is not your bootstrap component.

you always use `<app-root></app-root>` component in index.html file because this is the component which bootstraped in main module like this -

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

Answer (score 2):

import navbar in  `app-module.ts`  and  put the balise `<app-navbar></app-navbar>`  in  `app.component.html`